# how to get recent queries in oracle db

Tags: performance, oracle11g

I am debugging in cpu spikes in our oracle DB (amazon RDS, oracle-se1 11.2.0.2.v7) and trying to figure out the recent queries that are run that cause the spikes. I use the below query to do that, but somehow the below query does not show all the queries run by our application. This is because queries that are run are reported in our application logs, don't show up using the below query.

```
select sql_fulltext,LAST_LOAD_TIME,first_LOAD_TIME,last_active_time, cpu_time,executions,elapsed_time from v$sql 
order by LAST_LOAD_TIME desc
```

I also tried order by first_LOAD_TIME, last_active_time..still don't see all the queries. Is there any other query or any other way of monitoring performance?

Comment: `v$sql` only has the queries that are currently cached in the shared pool.  Queries that were purged won't be there.  Is Statspack installed on the database?  If so, that will capture the top queries every N minutes.  That still won't likely be every query the application sends but it should constitute the poor performers.

Comment: @JustinCave - StatsPack is not enabled or installed. It appears that Statspack jobs need to be run frequently to collect statistics....is this expensive db cpu wise?

Comment: It has a cost, yes.  It's generally not bad but you probably don't want to install it and start off by having it collect the maximum amount of data at the most frequent possible interval.  Unless you turned it off, Oracle is gathering basically the same information already into the AWR tables, you're just not licensed to use the collected data.  I haven't encountered a system where setting a snapshot interval of 15 or 20 minutes caused any noticable performance problems.  And the information you get will likely help you fix many more problems than the monitoring will create.

Comment: If it's a cluster then check GV$SQL instead of V$SQL.